# Concatenate multiple CSS files into one

Tags: css

What is the best way to concatenate multiple CSS files into one CSS file?

I want to reduce the following ..

```
<link href="css/1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="css/2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="css/3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

.. into ..

```
<link href="css/1-3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Simply doing `cat css/*.css > css/1-3.css` does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: Cat should work.  What happens when you try it?  Some rules don't work, no rules work, it can't find 1-3.css, etc?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're getting with cat css/*.css > css/1-3.css ?

Comment: The reason your cat doesn't work as expected is maybe because it doesn't include files in the right order.

Comment: I'm sorry what is 'cat' even related to? It's not native CSS functionality...is it? Is this some CSS framework or server side solution? I'd love to know.

Comment: Byran: "cat" is a standard Unix command used to concatenate files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as the **ordering** of the arguments for `cat` matches the original ordering of the three referenced CSS files in the HTML file the `cat`-method should work as expected.

So given say ..

```
<link href="css/one.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="css/two.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="css/three.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

.. the following concaternation ..

```
cat css/one.css css/two.css css/three.css > css/all.css
```

.. together will the following reference ..

```
<link href="css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

.. should be 100 % identical.

Answer (score 6):

At the beginning of 3.css you could add:

```
@import url(/css/1.css);
@import url(/css/2.css);
```

But i prefer using multiple link tags, or, even better, compressing my CSS into 1 file (using [YUI compressor](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor) for example).

Comment: +1 YUI compressor. Also, if you can code some clever server-side stuff you can automatically minify and cat when it's requested, means you don't have to worry about it when you want to change something in the original files.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [mod_concat](http://www.artzstudio.com/2008/08/using-modconcat-to-speed-up-render-start/) or a [PHP solution](http://rakaz.nl/code/combine) to combine your CSS and JS files.

FYI, Robert Nyman recently wrote an article about [optimizing CSS and JavaScript files](http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/19/tools-for-concatenating-and-minifying-css-and-javascript-files-in-different-development-environments/).

Answer (score 0):

You can always import your secondary CSS files from the main CSS that is included in the HTML.  Here's [a nice and simple tutorial](http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-import-rule/).