# Why does the website gradually slow down?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, nginx

My website turned slow suddenly today. My site is built on php, mysql,JS.
This site has been running properly for a long time and all of a sudden it became too slow. i had only 30 users on the site. and normally we have more that 100 at one time.

What i have noticed is: the site becomes faster as soon as i restart the php-fpm55

now i do not know how to actually figure out what the problem is?

What logs do i need to check?

Where do I need to add break points to?

Comment: could be a cache issue, temp files growing too big, mysql cache, memory, could be anything

Comment: and logs won't tell you if it's being memory hogged or anything else taking massive resources; that's only for errors and traffic

Comment: Thanks fred to get back - I have check the memory and CPU usage of  mysql, nginx, and php but all look fine

Comment: These may be of help http://serverfault.com/q/675520 --- http://serverfault.com/q/568830 --- http://serverfault.com/q/275275 --- http://serverfault.com/q/631820 --- http://serverfault.com/q/517552 --- http://stackoverflow.com/q/34428547/ - Just to name a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of factors that go into the speed of a site.

- check webserver logs (DDOS attack?) - if you know exactly when the slowdown occurs, you should be able to see what was requested just before it happened
- check mysql process list to see if there are runaway processes
- if using Linux, use top or htop to check your CPU and memory usage (or Task Manager in Windows)
- is it slow for only certain users? All users? Have each user run speed tests to make sure the problem isn't on their end.
- run a speed test on the webserver
- is the slowdown is on all pages or only certain ones? Check the code to see if something changed. (maybe you got hacked?)
- restart apache and mysql
- etc.

Comment: Hi @raphael75 - I I have checked point 1,2,3,6,7 - in pint 3 i can see many php-fpm55 process but the memory used it 1-5% , and it is slow for all users

Comment: If you restart php & mysql, how long does the site work normally before the slowdown?

Comment: Also, have you checked with your ISP, hosting company, etc. to make sure the issue isn't on their end? It could be a regional slowdown.

Comment: Hi Raphael- i figured it out. It was a cron that was causing it.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad you were able to find the source of the problem and especially that you posted it. That will help others in the future.